# How to add Lables to SWT Scale ticks?

Tags: swt, label, slider, scale

I have a SWT Scale widget, and I need to add labels to the ticks on the scale.

Is there a way to do this? maybe on a Slider widget?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*This might be not exactly what you are asking*, but you could incorporate a Text widget beside the Scale widget, responding to your Scale values.

For instance:

```
final Scale scale = new Scale(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL);   
        scaleValue = new Text(shell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);

        //scale properties omitted...

        scale.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                int perspectivevalue = scale.getSelection();
                scaleValue.setText("" + (perspectivevalue));
            }
        });
```

This has the effect of updating the value in the Text widget given whatever you drag the Scale slider to.